# nodejs sessions after refresh a page

Tags: node.js, ejs

**This is simple login form. I have validated a email, if email is not valid it gives an error( no problem here). After refreshing that page instead of showing login form  it also shows error along with login form on that page.**

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
//app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'ejs'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(expressSession({secret: 'max', saveUninitialized: false, resave: false}));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.session);
  res.render('student_login', { success: req.session.success, errors: req.session.errors });
  req.session.errors = null;
  console.log(req.session);
});

router.get('/submit', function(req, res, next) { 
  req.check('e', 'Invalid email address').isEmail();
  //req.check('p', 'Password is invalid').isLength({min: 4}).equals(req.body.confirmPassword);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    console.log(req.session);
    req.session.errors = errors;
    req.session.success = false;
    console.log(req.session);
  } else {
    console.log(req.session);
    req.session.success = true;
    console.log(req.session);
  }
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

student_login.ejs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

    <% if(success ){ %>
        <h1>validation succesful</h1>
    <% } 
    else{ %>
        <ul>
        <% if(errors) {%>
           <h1> errors </h1>
        <% } %>
        </ul>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="/submit" method="get"> 
        <input type="text" name="e" placeholder="Email" required="required" > <br>
        <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" > <br>
        <button type="submit" >Let me in.</button>
    </form>

<% } %>
</html>
```

Comment: can you format your code properly?

Comment: I have formatted it properly please check it

Comment: express itself does not have .check() method for request object

Comment: express validator have .check() method

Comment: I don't see any express-validator code here, please provide us with comprehensive code

Comment: I have included express-validator in app.js file

Comment: in your pjs file try with if(errors == null)

Comment: not working, the problem is after displaying ejs file i am making session.errors=null but after refresh it shows that req.sessions.errors is not null

Comment: maybe try to operate just on req.session.success, as at this point success is false when you fail to validate.

Comment: even that req.session.success changes after refreshing that page

Comment: seems like your session is not saved properly, check your session properties (like session id) in those 2 requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are saving your error in the session which means it will remain in the session unless you clear it out or the session ends.

What you need here is **flash messages**. These are similar messages stored in the session, but they are cleared once shown to the user, so they are shown only once.

I have used the [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) node module before. It is easy to set up and does the job perfectly.